# Casting from timestamp[us, tz=Etc/UTC] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a feature which let's me query a databricks delta table from a client app. This is the code I use for that purpose:

```
df = spark.sql('SELECT * FROM EmployeeTerritories LIMIT 100')
dataframe = df.toPandas()
dataframe_json = dataframe.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)
```

However, the second line throws me the error

> Casting from timestamp[us, tz=Etc/UTC] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp

I know what this error says, my date-type field is out of bounds and I tried searching for the solution but none of them were eligible for my scenario.

The solutions I found were about a specific dataframe column but in my case I have a global problem because I have tons of delta tables and I don't know the specific date-typed column so I can do type manipulation in order to avoid this.

Is it possible to find all `Timestamp` type columns and cast them to `string`? Does this seem like a good solution? Do you have any other ideas on how can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark toPandas() Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320966/pyspark-topandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-error)

Comment: No, it doesn't. This solution requires me to know the column name, which in my case is not a single one and different tables may have different column names with timestamp type.

Comment: can't you use [`schema`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.schema.html) to get these column names?

Answer (score 12):

> Is it possible to find all `Timestamp` type columns and cast them to
> string?

Yes, that's the way to go. You can loop through `df.dtype` and handle columns having `type = "timestamp"` by casting them into strings before calling `df.toPandas()`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.select(*[
    F.col(c).cast("string").alias(c) if t == "timestamp" else F.col(c)
    for c, t in df.dtypes
])

dataframe = df.toPandas()
```

You can define this as a function that take `df` as parameter and use it with all your tables:

```
def stringify_timestamps(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    return df.select(*[
        F.col(c).cast("string").alias(c) if t == "timestamp" else F.col(c).alias(c)
        for c, t in df.dtypes
    ])
```

If you want to preserve the timestamp type, you can consider nullifying the timestamp values which are greater than `pd.Timestamp.max` as shown in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320966/pyspark-topandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-error) instead of converting into strings.